# Missing references with ClickOnce deployment

Tags: c#, msbuild, clickonce

I have a WPF application. On my continuous integration server (Teamcity), I deploy the application with a MSbuild command that copy the ClickOnce files in a folder...

It was working until I added a new project in my solution and reference it in my main project.

It is still working in Visual Studio, but during the deployment with MSBuild I get an error :

> "The type or namespace name 'Blabla' does not exist in the namespace
>   'Bla.Bla' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Any idea why ?

The referenced project dll is well in the Application files list, in the publish tab of my main project properties...

Comment: Maybe it's set to not build in the release configuration? Open the configuration manager and take a look inside.